# Oozie java-action does not include core-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

When running an Oozie java action on a freshly installed Hadoop HDP 2.2.2.4, and for example tries to access hdfs it accesses the wrong filesystem:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs:/tmp/text.txt, expected: file:///`

It can be fixed by included the core-site.xml in the Oozie action:

```
<file>hdfs:/path-to-core-site.xml-on-hdfs</file>
```

But what is the reason and what is the proper fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of that the core-site.xml is not included in the class-path of the java-action is because the property *mapreduce.application.classpath* points to the wrong directory:

```
<snip>/etc/hadoop/conf/secure
```

It should point to

```
<snip>/etc/hadoop/conf
```

i.e, the full property should be something like, in *mapred-site.xml*:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
  <value>$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Those files are include in hadoop classpath, as I know since HDP 2.2, you need to add

```
// loading action conf prepared by Oozie
Configuration actionConf = new Configuration(false);
actionConf.addResource(new Path("file:///", System.getProperty("oozie.action.conf.xml")));
```

to use *-site.xml, you can get the details in oozie document
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action

Comment: The point is that the path in the classpath is wrong, at least on our secured cluster: "/etc/hadoop/conf/secure" when it should be "/etc/hadoop/conf"